# AngularJS - set common Basic Auth header that is applied to all http requests

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-headers, basic-authentication

I am using AngularJS with Play REST services on the back end and I'm fairly new to both concepts.
I want to know if there is a way in which I can write the Basic Auth header at just one place so that is is added by default to every http request that is being made by Angular.

Right now I am adding this line at the beginning of every request.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
```

I want it to be present at just one place instead of multiple places for easier code maintainability. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using an $http interceptor in your **angular.config**

```
var app = angular.module();
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvier){

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function(){

  return {
    request: function(config) {
      config.headers.Authorization = YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER;
      return config;
    }
  }

  });

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Robin for your answer. Could you please demonstrate a full example?

Comment: Here's the code I'm using for a project. It uses loopback (www.loopback.io) to log in, loopback returns a token and I save it to my localStorage on response. On request I add the token to my auth header which causes me to be authorized :-)

http://pastebin.com/Xr69e4BV

Comment: Gotcha. I added my stuff appropriately and it's working :) Thank you so much! @Robin